# how to store if statement result in an array

Tags: java

how to have these string values in an array. its giving me the output loc[j]==1 is simple loc[j]>1 is extended. but am storing this in string.. i need to store these values in string array . how do i do it

```
      String s = (loc[j]==1 ? "simple" : (loc[j]>1 ? "extended" : null));
```

this is equivalent to this code

```
          if(loc[j]==1)
         System.out.println("Simple");
         else
           System.out.println("extended");
```

Comment: The code you are saying equavalent is not equavalent.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make array of strings.
2. Store strings in array.

Like so:

```
String[] results = new String[loc.length]; // Looks like it should be the same length as loc. If not, change it as needed.
// later on, presumably in a for loop or something
results[j] = (loc[j]==1 ? "simple" : (loc[j]>1 ? "extended" : null));
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is `single` value then no need to use array. Learn how to use [Java arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) (Tutorial)

```
String s=null;
if(loc[j]==1) //I presume that loc is an array of int
  s="Simple";
else
if(loc[j]>1)
  s="extended";
```

Comment: @user977830 - Then explain us what you want to do.